# Sharing login between mobile application and web site

Tags: php, android, ios, session, mobile

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to perform a sort of single sign on, sharing the login between the mobile site for a product and its native application implementation.
Basically, a user perform the login on the mobile site and he also become logged in into the mobile application (if installed) and vice versa, assuming he's using the same device. Is it possible? If yes, the same concept can be also applied to the same user surfing from different devices?

Thanks!